# BLOB or VARBINARY to store simple Strings that are converted into byte[ ]?

Tags: mysql, performance, blob, varbinary, query-performance

I've read that In MySQL, BLOBs are often used to store image files, file path pointers, video & audio files, and any other big data objects.

But can BLOBs be used for simple Strings that are converted into byte[] (like names, address, etc.) or would VARBINARY suffice?

Or does it not really impact the database size and query performance?

Answer (score 2):

Main differences between [VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) and [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) are:

- VARBINARY must have length specification, BLOB must not (but may);
- Index by BLOB must have prefix length specification, VARBINARY must not (but may);
- VARBINARY may have default value, BLOB cannot.

> can BLOBs be used for simple Strings that are converted into byte[] (like names, address, etc.) or would VARBINARY suffice?

Both variants are possible. The influence on the query performance depends of the query.

Answer (score 2):

> does it not really impact the database size and query performance.

As per MySQL documentation [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) In most respects, you can regard a BLOB column as a [VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) column that can be as large as you like. Similarly, you can regard a TEXT column as a [VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) column. BLOB and TEXT differ from [VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) and [VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) in the following ways:

- For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index
  prefix length. For CHAR and VARCHAR, a prefix length is optional. See

  [Section 8.3.5, “Column Indexes”"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html).
- BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values
- Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is
  processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on
  disk rather than in memory because the MEMORY storage engine does not
  support those data types (see 
  [Section 8.4.4, “Internal Temporary Table Use in MySQL”)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html). Use of
  disk incurs a performance penalty, so include BLOB or TEXT columns in
  the query result only if they are really needed. For example, avoid
  using [SELECT
  *](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), which selects all columns.
- The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type,
  but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client
  and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the
  size of the communications buffers. You can change the message buffer
  size by changing the value of the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)
  variable, but you must do so for both the server and your client
  program. For example, both [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html)
  and [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)
  enable you to change the client-side  [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)
  value. See  [Section 5.1.1, “Configuring the Server”, Section 4.5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration.html), [“mysql —
  The MySQL Command-Line Tool”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), and [Section
  4.5.4, “mysqldump — A Database Backup Program”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). You may also want to compare the packet sizes and the size of the data objects you are
  storing with the storage requirements, see [Section
  11.8, “Data Type Storage Requirements”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Each BLOB or TEXT value is represented internally by a separately allocated object. This is in contrast to all other data types, for which storage is allocated once per column when the table is opened.

In some cases, it may be desirable to store binary data such as media files in BLOB or TEXT columns. You may find MySQL's string handling functions useful for working with such data. See [Section 12.5, “String Functions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html). For security and other reasons, it is usually preferable to do so using application code rather than giving application users the [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege.